# NodeJS: Array doesnt save

Tags: node.js

I have a `Budskap` (post) which has `replies` array and every reply has `likes` array in it. Now I have this code:

```
    const budskapFromDB = await Budskap.findById(budskapID);

    const budskapReply = await budskapFromDB.replies.find(r => r.id === replyID);

    budskapReply.likes.push({
        username: req.user.username,
        createdAt: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
    });

    budskapFromDB.save();
```

Which finds corresponding `budskap` by ID then I find the reply that I want to like and to that reply push the `username`. When `save()` is called the array of `likes` still remains empty. Why it's not saveing new element in `likes` array ?

**UPDATE**

Okay so pushing the `budskapReply` to the `budskapFromDB.replies` adds it with new data but duplicates with old like from before.

```
    budskapReply.likes.push({
        username: req.user.username,
        createdAt: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
    });

    budskapFromDB.replies.push(budskapReply)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so replaceing the old reply with the new one did the trick.

```
    budskapReply.likes.push({
        username: req.user.username,
        createdAt: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
    });

    budskapFromDB.replies.splice(replyIndex, 1, budskapReply); // <--- trick

    budskapFromDB.save();
```